# Getting localstorage object into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I ma trying to figure out how to retrieve an object saved into an localStorage. The object is an user from parse.com and are stored like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("USERDATA", JSON.stringify(data[0]));
```

When then trying to retrieve it later I am trying to do this:

```
var user = localStorage.getItem("USERDATA");
user = JSON.stringify(user);
console.log("WHAT: "+user['fname']);
```

This gives me an log like this:

```
WHAT: undefined
```

When just logging the user variable it looks like this:

```
WHAT: "{\"sqlID\":48,\"fname\":\"Me\",\"lname\":\"Test\",\"objectId\":\"Iy2JzIi7LH\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-03-01T13:04:28.048Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2014-03-01T13:04:28.048Z\"}"
```

I have been trying this all day but can't find the solution... Please help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Variables from local storage is basically a string.. You have to parse it before accessing the values in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way around. `JSON.parse(user)`/`$.parseJSON(user)` to fetch properties

```
var data = '{\"sqlID\":48,\"fname\":\"Me\",\"lname\":\"Test\",\"objectId\":\"
            Iy2JzIi7LH\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-03-01T13:04:28.048Z\",\"updatedAt\"
            :\"2014-03-01T13:04:28.048Z\"}',
    user = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(user.fname, user['fname']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bu9vJ/1/